# Android action bar using "search filter bar"

Tags: android, action, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

For my project I want to add search filters at the bottom of the action bar.

Example for this is the [youtube app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ae4ddomz86a4lqv/2012-07-31%2012.39.55.png)

I don't know how to get the bar below the action bar with the search filters in my app.
As far as I know it is a feature of the action bar API.

I'm using `ActionbarSherlock` to support versions below 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's **not supported** in current version of ActionBarSherlock 4.1

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/70